# Return to previous function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm using ajax to check if a username is taken. If the username is taken it returns false to the form submit function. I'm using MySQL.

**index.php**

```
$("#register-form").submit(function(){
    var un = $("#un").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "user_check.php",
        dataType: "html",
        data: {un: un},
        success: function(data){

        }
    });
});
```

**user_check.php**

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","webcap");
$user = $_POST['un'];
$query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$un'");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
echo $count;
```

How I return false to the register form submit function if data is 1 or true if it's 0? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Mind the Sql injection!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JSON. In the PHP do:

```
echo json_encode($count > 0);
```

And in the Javascript, specify `type: 'json'` instead of `type: 'html'`. Then `data` will be `true` or `false`.

However, since AJAX is asynchronous, you can't return a value from this.

What you need to do is prevent normal form submission in the `.submit()` function. Then in the `success:` function, check the response and submit the form if it was successful.

```
$("#register-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var un = $("#un").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "user_check.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {un: un},
        success: function(data){
            if (data) {
                $("#register-form")[0].submit(); // really submit the form
            } else {
                alert("Username is taken");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @splash58 You shouldn't, so I ignore that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
<script>
    $("#register-form").submit(function(){
    var un = $("#un").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "user_check.php",
        data: {un: un},
        success: function(data){
           alert(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>

<?php 

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","webcap");
$user = $_POST['un'];
$query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$user."'");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
echo $count;
if($count>0){echo TRUE;}
else{echo FALSE;}
?>
```